# Ellipsis didn't work well on Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I am trying to use `text-overflow: ellipsis` to truncate text on my website. It displays correctly in Firefox, but does not display in IE; I have included my code and examples of how it displays in both Firefox and IE below:

```
.ellipsis {
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 1.2em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 150px;
}
```

[image: Elippis on IE and Firefox]

Comment: Did you try `-ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;`?

Comment: text-overflow has been available as of IE6, so you do not need to use a Microsoft vendor prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, because I use a tag to wrap the div tag so IE work not well.

I moved a tag to inside div tag and it work well. Thank everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

*`text-overflow`* has been [available as of IE6](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-overflow), so you do not need to use a Microsoft vendor prefix. You might, however need those extensions for Opera and Webkit depending on what your site plans to support.

What version of Internet Explorer are you testing this in?

You can obviously use [jQuery plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/ellipsis) for this same functionality fairly easily, but you shouldn't need to if IE is your only issue because, as stated, it should support the feature.

Here is a simple reproduction of code that should work using this functionality:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>text-overflow: ellipsis</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .ellipsis { 
        height: 1.2em; 
        overflow: hidden; 
        text-overflow: ellipsis; 
        white-space: nowrap; 
        width: 150px; 
    } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ellipsis">
            This is a test of the less-than-emergency 
            broadcast system. This is only a test.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```